# How do I get the recommend plugin into the right side panel on my business page?

Tags: html, facebook-recommendations

I have researched this for a few days now, and I haven't been able to find anything.

[Example](https://www.facebook.com/GoodDonor?sk=wall)

You can see in the top right, the recommendation plugin is there.  The [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/recommendations) for the plugin  says "Place the code for your plugin wherever you want the plugin to appear on your page." but I can't manually put stuff in the right panel (right?).  So I was thinking that maybe there was an admin setting to show the plugin, but after rigorous searching I could not find anything.

Does anyone have any ideas that can point me in right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommend plugin at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/recommendations is for external websites only.  The recommend box on right of a Facebook page is auto generated to newer users in your fan base, or just randomly when content is needed for fill.

Comment: the link is posted in the answer Keith

Comment: Where on that link does it say about it being for external use only, and that it is auto generated?

Comment: Keith, assuming you are actually trying to add the plugin to the Fan Page on Facebook, it is known that you cannot modify the Fan page in that manner.  You can however use the Fan Page url in the button so users can recommend you page from an external website. The documents do not state "for external sites only, it is assumed" i appologise.  You can take my word for it, from experience.